# Apache Poi default timezone

Tags: apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to evaluate every formula cell of a workbook.
When a cell contains a call to the standard excel function NOW(), Poi evalutes it correctly and replaces the call with the current time - formatted in the default timezone of the VM. I would like to adjust this timezone. Is there any way to change the timezone of DateUtil?

I found the code of the NOW Implementation in 3.14-beta1, I attach it for reference:

```
/**
 * Implementation of Excel NOW() Function
 *
 * @author Frank Taffelt
 */
 public final class Now extends Fixed0ArgFunction {
     public ValueEval evaluate(int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex) {
        Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return new NumberEval(DateUtil.getExcelDate(now));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look into `org.apache.poi.util.LocaleUtil.setUserTimeZone()`, which is used by `DateUtil`. This has to be set per Thread.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I was looking for. Why did you not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I add the solution as an answer too ... (i.e. I still think I'm young and needed the votes ...)

Starting with [POI 3.13](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.13) we've added a [`org.apache.poi.util.LocaleUtil`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/util/LocaleUtil.java?view=log) class, to handle Locale specific requests within POI. There's a `setUserTimeZone()` method to handle your issue. This needs to be set per Thread - so before opening or creating a workbook, call that function with your [`TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)) object.
Usually it's a good idea to [clear ThreadLocals in the end of processing](https://techblog.bozho.net/threadlocal-variables-and-thread-pools-it-can-go-wrong/), especially if you deal with thread pools, so please call `resetUserTimeZone()` in a `finally` block.

Although we've taken care to prevent unnoticed/default handling of TimeZone/Locale related calls via the [Forbidden Apis Tool](https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis) - I wouldn't bet, that we've covered all cases. If you notice any irregularities, please open a [ticket](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI&component=POI%20Overall).

Comment: Problem is, CellFormat caches the instance in a static cache based on the format string alone, so whoever calls getInstance first is the one who decides which locale to use.